# JPQL Member condition equivalent in Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, jpa-2.1

I have a very useful query in JPQL:

```
select count(p) from Project p, in (p.members) s where s.members.email = :email
```

or again

```
select p from Project p, in (p.members) s where s.members.email = :email order by p.lastUpdate desc
```

It is fast, easy to understand and works flawlessly. It even works great when the relationship is no a @*ToMany but a @ElementCollection.

Now I need to convert the `in (p.members) s where s.members.email = :email` to Criteria API so that I can replicate this pattern of query across many similar entities, or also add "orderBy" and other conditions programmatically and I'd rather not do it through `String` manipulation, I am familiar with the basic uses of Criteria API but I am by no way an expert.

I have tried the `CriteriaBuilder.in(~)` but it seems to be a totally different meaning ... or maybe I am using it wrong.

Could someone help?

I am using Hibernate 4.3.0 behind JPA 2.1 (in Play!Framework).

Comment: According to the spec, `from Project p, in (p.members) s` is equivalent to `from Program p join p.members s`, so try using a join instead.

Comment: Thanks it did work. So no "look alike" in Criteria API?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'd be surprised if there wasn't an equivalent criteria expression, but I personally always use the join pattern.